# Haskell -- bidirectional class instance type implications OR GADT existential type qualifications?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, algebraic-data-types, gadt

I have a GADT defined like (abbreviated),

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
data D t where
    C :: t -> D t
    R :: D b -> D (Either a b)
deriving instance Show t => Show (D t)
```

The compiler correctly complains that it cannot derive Show for R. In this case, we have that (Either a b) is of class Show, but we can't know that this is true iff b is of class Show. The error message is,

```
Could not deduce (Show b) from the context (t ~ Either a b)
  arising from a use of `showsPrec' at tmp.hs:37:0-37
Possible fix: add (Show b) to the context of the constructor `R'
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(showsPrec 11 b1)'
In the second argument of `showParen', namely
    `((.) (showString "R ") (showsPrec 11 b1))'
In the expression:
    showParen ((a >= 11)) ((.) (showString "R ") (showsPrec 11 b1))
When typechecking a standalone-derived method for `Show (D t)':
  showsPrec a (C b1)
              = showParen ((a >= 11)) ((.) (showString "C ") (showsPrec 11 b1))
  showsPrec a (R b1)
              = showParen ((a >= 11)) ((.) (showString "R ") (showsPrec 11 b1))
```

It seems that one needs to be able to qualify over the existential type, saying something like "Show b => Show (D (Either a b))" for existential types b, or upgrade the implication "(Show a, Show b) => Show (Either a b)" so it is bidirectional.

Thanks very much!

(Please feel free to clean up the title or description.)

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know how to write the Show instance by hand, or you can't get GHC to derive it for you?  If the latter is your problem, could you give us the hand-written Show instance so we can see what you're hoping to accomplish?  By the way, just because you can show (Either X Y) doesn't mean you can necessarily show Y!  It's totally legitimate to implement "instance Show (Either X Y) where ..." without implementing "instance Show Y".

Comment: I need it to do something meaningful though, i.e. it `show (Left x)` should be the same as `show x` if `x` is of class `Show`.

Comment: Sorry, this is not related to your question, but I'm kind of curious how you came up with that data declaration. Why the existential `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 4):

Add the `Show` constraint to the existential,

```
data D t where
    C :: t -> D t
    R :: Show b => D b -> D (Either a b)
```

and you're in business.

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling A                ( A.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: A.
*A> R (C 7)
R (C 7)
```

Comment: I already tried that, and it won't work form my case, since this class forms the basis of an arrow value type, which needs to work on all _b_, whether they derive Show or not. I want to write code that says, any "D" value whose arguments (existential types) derive Show should be showable.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: I don't think it's possible to make GHC derive this, at least in part because the deriving mechanism doesn't work well with GADT's.  However, it's very easy to manually write the `Show` instance you want.